# How can I ignore and fix unmet dependencies on apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, kde, dependencies

I have tried to install a few different desktop environments on Ubuntu 16.04, but when trying to install `kubuntu-desktop`, it ran but at the end of the operation it errors out. Now when ever I run something on `apt-get`, it NEVER finishes! It just gives me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0)  but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`
```

When I run `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
439 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 430234 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-    accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.13+16.04.20160810-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried removing and purging `kubuntu-desktop`, but it gives me the same error code and doesn't do anything. I tried removing and purging `kde-config-telepathy`. 'kde-telepathy'. `kde`. nothing works! This is getting frustrating, what is going on? How can I fix this? I definitely don't want to reinstall Ubuntu, I have a lot of apps installed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you observe the output, you will find this line.

```
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', 
which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.13+16.04.20160810-0ubuntu1
```

Problem is one of the files is already present in the system installed by some other package (*account-plugin-google*) which is getting overwritten by the new package you were trying to install. 

However dpkg is not going to overwrite it until you are not specifying it.

So you have 2 options

1. Purge the old one and install the new one or
2. overwrite the file with the new one.

In your case, I will prefer the second solution.
To solve this problem, execute this command

```
sudo dpkg -i  --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-
telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Thanks! Used the same operations on a different computer and got stuck again, I think it was because I was trying to install the Chrome OS desktop environment. Anyway, ran the commands and fixed it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The command to have Ubuntu fix unmet dependencies and broken packages is sudo apt-get install -f
from the man page:

> -f, --fix-broken Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages)
>   Blockquote

Ubuntu will try to fix itself when you run the command. When it completes, you can test if it worked by running the command again, and you should receive output similar to:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

After much Googling and experimenting, I finall figured it out. Open synaptic, select status, and then click broken. Completely remove anything there, and then it works again. Almost like magic. But I still don't understand why you can't install anything until that's fixed... computers still have a long way to go, I guess.

Comment: how do i install synaptic if i have an `unmet dependencies` error?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get -f install`? If I remember correctly, this will ask you if you want to remove conflicting packages. Then run `sudo apt-get update`. If you want to install Synaptic for a GUI interface to investigate the problem further, you can now install it: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`.